# angular filter groupby with orderby

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm trying to order a groupBy list by the group values (date and time). I'm using the [angular-filter library](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

**This are the data**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-04",
    "time": "17:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-03",
    "time": "12:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-01",
    "time": "12:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-02",
    "time": "09:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "pickupDate": "2016-03-01",
    "time": "10:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-01",
    "time": "11:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-13",
    "time": "14:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "pickupDate": "2015-12-02",
    "time": "11:15"
  }
]
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

1. Grouping the data by the ID propery (done by | groupBy: 'id')
2. Ordering the groups by taken the smallest datetime from the groups

I'm struggling with ordering.

**Here how the list should look like**

```
3
    01-12-2015 - 11:00
    01-03-2016 - 10:00

2
    01-12-2015 - 12:00
    02-12-2015 - 09:00

4
    02-12-2015 - 11:15
    13-12-2015 - 14:00  

1
    03-12-2015 - 12:00
    04-12-2015 - 17:00
```

Here the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwT1CXKJxIAU1AMV6q8w?p=preview)

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue actually? I don't get the point...

Comment: @beat - Thanks for your time! I edited my post. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I end up writing my own filter. I used the lib underscore.

here my solution in typescript.

```
module App {

    export interface IFooFilter extends ng.IFilterService {
        (name:"foo-filter"): (collection:any[]) => any[];
    }

    class FooFilter {
        static $inject:string[] = ["underscore"];

        static ConvertDateAndTime(item:any):number {
            return item.pickupDate.replace(/\-/g, '') + item.time.replace(':', '');
        }

        public static Factory(underscore:UnderscoreStatic) {
            return underscore.memoize((collection:any[]) => {
                var groupKey = "id";

                var group:any = underscore.groupBy(collection, (item:any) => {
                    return item[groupKey];
                });

                var grpArray = [];
                angular.forEach(group, (item) => {
                    grpArray.push({
                        "groupKey": item[0][groupKey],
                        "items": item
                    });
                });

                var grpArraySorted = underscore.sortBy(grpArray, (grpObj:any) => {

                    var min:any = underscore.min(grpObj.items, (item:any) => {
                        return FooFilter.ConvertDateAndTime(item);
                    });

                    return FooFilter.ConvertDateAndTime(min);
                });

                return grpArraySorted;
            });
        }
    }

    angular.module("app").filter("fooFilter", FooFilter.Factory);
}
```

[here the link to plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCbGBQ1CQL2UGCzu1PjX?p=preview)